# C++ Allocating memory for buffer errors in free()

Tags: c++, memory-management

I need to store some tuples of this data into a buffer.

```
"1444394028","1","5339","M","873" 
"1444394028","1","7045","V","0.34902"
"1444394028","1","7042","M","2"
"1444394028","1","7077","V","0.0470588"
"1444394028","1","5415","M","40"
```

As you can see, the length of the records varies. One line equals one record. I've written this function:

```
std::string data_string = (record.asString());
char* data =   (char*) malloc (data_string.length() );            
std::copy( data_string.begin(), data_string.end(), data );
data[data_string.length()] = 0;
ressourceBuffer.push_back(data);
```

Now I can work with the buffer fairly well, but if I want to free the memory, I run into errors. My free function looks like this:

```
/* free memory */
for (const char* b : ressourceBuffer) {
    free ((char*) b);
}
```

I really can't find a solution and am running out of ideas. It creates this error (these are the first lines from about 50 in the stacktrace):

```
*** Error in `./build-debug/bin/Test': free(): invalid next 
size (fast): 0x00000000019b3cb0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7da1389d97e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7da1389e237a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7da1389e653c]
```

Comment: Avoid `malloc` in C++ and avoid raw pointers while at it. Use smart pointers or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You already have a std::string - why not use that?

Comment: should be `malloc (data_string.length() + 1 );` if you want to write null character `data[data_string.length()] = 0;`

Comment: @Ron           I know this for sure, but in this case there is no other solution. Ressourcebuffer is already a vector. The first code is a loop, and there is really no other way to make sure that data is properly written into memory.

Comment: @rafix07       good idea, will try.

Comment: @Baesm If there is no other solution then we are probably talking about C, not C++. Chances are you need to rethink the approach.

Comment: @rafix07       that fixed it! Maybe I was tired writing this and forgot the terminating 0.

Comment: I assume `ressourceBuffer` is `std::vector<char *>`? Why not make it a `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]>>` if you care much about overhead?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  because another interface who needs the ressourceBuffer only works with `const char*` or `char*`.

Comment: @Baesm `std::string::c_str` is I think what you're looking for

Comment: Learn to use `valgrind`

Comment: @Ron I suggest that developers avoid *owning* raw pointers. That is, pointers that own the object they point to. Once in a while, a *non-owning* raw pointer is just the right tool for the job.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I agree.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as already said in comments you should rather not use `malloc` in C++; there are implications of it not being considered by the standard in several regards, which can make it painful to use. Use `new`, or, preferably, standard containers. Also use `static_cast` and companions over C-style casts.

Second:

`data[data_string.length()] = 0;`

writes one past the end of the buffer. Let `N` be `data_string.length()`

`char* data =   (char*) malloc (data_string.length() );`

allocates `N` bytes, with indexes `0` to `N - 1` being in the allocated memory. `N` is therefor outside of the allocated memory. I cannot guarantee to you that this is your problem, though.

Which brings me to third: post a minimum complete example please. The snippets you provide are not sufficient to really tell what's going on. What is `ressourceBuffer`, and what is `resource` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should model the text lines as a structure:

```
struct Record
{
  std::string field1; // Rename with column name
  std::string field2;
  std::string field3;
  std::string field4;
}
```

Next, overload `operator>>` to read in the record:

```
struct Record
{
  //...
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  // Read column data until the ',' but don't put ',' into string.
  std::getline(input, r.field1, ',');
  std::getline(input, r.field2, ',');
  std::getline(input, r.field3, ',');
  std::getline(input, r.field4);
}
```

The above allows you to create a *database* using `std::vector` and simplify reading of the file:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (my_data_file >> r)
{
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

The above will simplify the database creation.

Also, the above code allows you to handle variable length records.

By using `std::vector`, you don't need to concern yourself about `malloc`, `free`, `new` or `delete`.  The `std::vector` handles memory allocation so you don't need to.

Later, you may want to change the `operator>>` method to read numeric fields as numbers and remove the `"` from the strings (see `std::string::find` and `std::string::erase`).